# How to call certain apis without caching a response in angular when using service worker?

Tags: node.js, angular, http-status-code-302, http-caching, angular-service-worker

I Have attached 2 images.
First Image is the very fist time when I load the website where the service-worker is registered. There are 2 arrow mark that shows 302 found and sets the cookies of session information.
[image]

This is the second time (refer the below image) , After I sign out and sign in again using google i am getting the below image as a response. You can see from the image there are no cookies set and it is actually from service worker.

[image]

This is my ngsw-config.json , from the docs [Reference](https://angular.io/guide/service-worker-config#:%7E:text=Possible%20values%3A,is%20temporarily%20down.) I have made it as   "navigationRequestStrategy": "freshness", But still it doesnt work.

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/service-worker/config/schema.json",
  "index": "/index.html",
  "navigationUrls": [
    "! /**/*callback*"
  ],
  "navigationRequestStrategy": "freshness",
  "assetGroups": [
    {
      "name": "app",
      "installMode": "prefetch",
      "resources": {
        "files": [
          "/favicon.ico",
          "/manifest.webmanifest",
          "/*.css",
          "/*.js"
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "assets",
      "installMode": "lazy",
      "updateMode": "prefetch",
      "resources": {
        "files": [
          "/assets/**",
          "/*.(eot|svg|cur|jpg|png|webp|gif|otf|ttf|woff|woff2|ani)"
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So the service worker was caching the api response and returned from the cache. To bypass the service worker for certain apis. Either add salt or use `ngsw-bypass` in the queryparams.

[Bypass Service Worker Caching in APIs](https://angular.io/guide/service-worker-devops#bypassing-the-service-worker)